# use instruments - leaks with a device

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, instruments, memory-leak-detector

I'm starting to use Instruments-Leaks with an iPhone 3G. When I try to run the app with Instruments on the iPhone I obtain

```
Target failed to run: Remote exception encountered: 'Failed to get task for pid 280'
```

Ideas?

The only time I succeed in running the app with instruments it run very slow, I couldn't test it. 
What are the steps to run the app on the device searching for leaks?

Comment: Although I can't directly help you with your issue, [here](http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/) is a guide that I recently found helpful. It walks you through a sample project and shows you how to use instruments to find leaks.

Comment: Thanks. Now it runs, but it's still very slow...

Comment: This may be a good tutorial, but is unhelpful with respect the error: 'Failed to get task for pid XXX'

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The solution for me was to make sure that my Profile scheme was using  the "debug" and not "release" build configuration.

In Xcode 4 select Product/Edit Scheme from the top menu
then click on the "profile" button on the left. 
On the "info" pane you will see a setting for Build Configuration- set that to "debug"

Comment: You may need to restart Xcode/clean/delete app on device (some combination of these).

Comment: This isn't really a fix right? Profiling should be on the Release build.

Comment: wish I could tripe upvote this. I think I've come back to this about 3 times or so... Thanks!

Comment: @pumpk1n would be nice if it could be on the release build, but if release builds don't have the hooks needed to attach a profiler...

Comment: @bogardon is correct. Profiling (instruments) should be done on RELEASE build. There is nothing to stop you from profiling a running release build. You can manually attach instruments after the process has started...

Answer (score 28):

This error is also thrown if you are trying to test your app on a device with a distribution profile selected. Make sure you have the correct code-sign settings for development.

Comment: If this is indeed correct, this is the best answer -- the above highly-rated answer will also solve the problem, but for those of us that have significant performance differences between Debug & Release profiles, it makes a difference to simply use Debug...

Answer (score 6):

You CAN profile the release build on the device.  What you have to do is build the release build with a developer certificate.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442324/why-wont-instruments-execute-my-monotouch-application).

Answer (score 0):

Instruments basically does its work by becoming the debugger for the app. If you can't run Xcode's debugger against it, then you can't run Instruments against it.

Mostly, entitlements need to be set to allow debugging.

Sometimes after using XCode to debug apps, I find I can't use Instruments until I reboot the device.

Unlike XCode, Instruments can be confused between two apps with the same name, but different bundle IDs. (Or perhaps same name and similar bundle IDs.) When I have multiple versions of an app on a device, I often have to delete the extra to get Instruments to connect to the correct app. If you have one debug build and one release build, this could be the problem.

So, delete any duplicates of your app and restart the device.  (You could change the display name for release and debug build configurations.)