# Using Instruments with MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

How do I configure my application to be profiled by Instruments?

Does it work using the simulator... or the actual device?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: I had a similar question, that was answered, and may be of help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442324/why-wont-instruments-execute-my-monotouch-application

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Xamarin profiling documentation(http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Profiling). You can use Instruments on both the device and the simulator depending on what you select in Instruments. However, according to the Xamarin docs, profiling only works for MonoTouch apps on the device.

Comment: Link is dead. Can you update it? Is it still true that you can select the simulator in Instruments? I can choose target, but then I have to navigate to a folder/file ...

Comment: New profiling links are http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/monotouch_profiler/ and http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/using_instruments_to_detect_native_leaks_using_markheap/