# How do I get rid of 'Failed to get task for pid" error?

Tags: xcode, instruments

This doesn't seem to be going away.

Here's the problem - I choose Product > Profile in XCode. Instruments opens, asks what I'd like to track, I choose Time Profiler, and it opens, but won't let me start the task, stating the error

> Target failed to run: Remote exception encountered: 'Failed to get task for pid 1461'".

The 1461 changes to something different every time.

In Xcode, I have my Profile scheme's build configuration set to "Debug". In the target's build settings I have Code Signing Identity set to iPhone Developer for everything right now. In the project's build settings I have the same.

How can I get rid of this error, so I can test my app?

EDIT: Turns out I had to delete the app from my phone, and I did Product > Clean along with restarting xcode too.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me was to make sure that my Profile scheme was using the "debug" and not "release" build configuration.

In Xcode 4 select Product/Edit Scheme from the top menu then click on the "profile" button on the left. On the "info" pane you will see a setting for Build Configuration- set that to "debug"

Thanks,

Comment: You may need to restart Xcode/clean/delete app on device (some combination of these).

Comment: thanks dost. i will give also give you upvote in another answers of yours

Comment: No worries keep happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

For others coming by this question:

For me, the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323369/use-instruments-leaks-with-a-device) worked:

> The solution for me was to make sure that my Profile scheme was using the "debug" and not "release" build configuration.
>
> In Xcode 4 select Product/Edit Scheme from the top menu then click on the "profile" button on the left. On the "info" pane you will see a setting for Build Configuration- set that to "debug"

Comment: I would never copy anything without giving credit to the source. Please have a look at the timestamps of the answers and reconsider who copied from who ;-) Do you think I ought to delete my answer?